# Ошибка TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, списки

Есть следующий код на python:

```
matrix = []
for p in range(9):
    matrix.append([])
    for l in range(9):
        matrix.append(False)
i = 3
j = 5
if matrix[i][j] == False:
    print ('False')
```

При запуске появляется ошибка: TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: После первой итерации внешнего цикла разве matrix  не имеет вид [ [], false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]? То есть matrix[3] равно false.

Comment: Согласен, понял, что было неправильно, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь прикрепить булевое значение массиву, вам необходимо добавлять значение в только что созданный массив

```
matrix[p].append(False)
```